# Dynamic url's redirect from old to new url's using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I want to `redirect` below two `dynamic url` from old url's to new url's using `.htaccess` and i have done this application using `codeigniter`.

**1)** This are the dynamic url's and there are more than thousands of url's in my database.

Old(From) URL

`https://www.example.com/area-name/pangothe-263001`

New(To) URL

`https://www.example.com/pangothe-263001`

**2)** This are the `amp` version of the above url.

Old(From) URL

`https://www.example.com/amp-area-name/pangothe-263001`

New(To) URL

`https://www.example.com/pangothe-263001/amp`

I have tried with below code

```
RewriteRule ^area-name$ http://www.example.com/area-name [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^amp-area-name$ http://www.example.com/amp-area-name [R=301,L]
```

But not redirecting to the new urls. How can do this redirect using `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep these 2 redirect rules **just below `RewriteEngine` line**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^area-name/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]

RewriteRule ^amp-area-name/(.+)$ /$1/amp [R=301,L,NC,NE]

# remaining rules go below this
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
RewriteRule ^area-name/pangothe-263001/?$ $1/pangothe-263001$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: `pangothe-263001` is a dynamic part , not static one

Comment: Whatever i tried that, but not redirecting and getting 404 page.

Comment: if the links are dynamic then use pre_system hooks for it , fetch the new url or send modified url in header function in hook code

Comment: No, I want this to be redirect from .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below rules,

### Canonical links Redirect

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/area-name/(.*)$
```

### AMP links Redirect

```
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/%1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/amp-area-name/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/%1/amp [R=301]
```

Comment: Getting 404 page